# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I first tried to change the $1$ in the denominator so I could use the theorem $\cos x - \cos y = -2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\sin\frac{x-y}{2}$ But if I do that, the ultimate result will be $$\frac{1}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

I think I'm heading at it the wrong way. Could someone push me on the right track?

Comment: The denominator tends to zero, but the nominatior doesn't. Hence, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: More  precisely, $1-\cos x\to 0^+$, hence there is a generalised limit, which is $+\infty$.

Comment: @Jochen Tecnically limit exist. It's not just finite $+\infty$

Comment: @lonestudent personally, I wouldn't say that a limit exists when it is $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @Alann This is completely different case. Two sided limit are not equal. But this is not our case .(I think)

Comment: @lonestudent : For a limit to exist in calculus of a real variable, the limit must be a real number.  Neither $\infty$ nor $-\infty$ are real numbers.  However, both types of limit behaviour are both common and useful, so we have special notation for these two types of nonexistent limits.  (The situation changes in real analysis, when we extend the reals to include $\infty$ and $-\infty$, but this does not make either of those real numbers.)

Comment: @lonestudent I know that. The $\pm\infty$ was meant to be interpreted as the "value" of any limit, two-sided or one-sided; if it helps, replace $\pm\infty$ with "infinite" in my original comment. For instance, I wouldn't say that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}$ exists, even though $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}=\infty$.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you. I didn't take calculus courses. Can I ask a question? Technically, these two situations are different from each other, right?  For example, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac 1x$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac 1{x^2}$?

Comment: @lonestudent : Yes.  Neither limit exists.  However, we can write $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$ because it does exhibit that particular limit behaviour (on both the left and right of $0$, which is where we get stuck trying to write something analogous for the first limit).

Comment: @EricTowers  In the second case, we can prove that the limit $\to +\infty$ with epsilon-delta, right?  But in the first case we can't do that.  So epsilon delta won't work because we have $±\infty$  But in the second case epsilon delta works. I'm a little confused here..

Comment: @lonestudent : The epsilon-delta method shows that neither limit exists.  So it is not clear what you mean.  I note that you are currently posting on a site for answering questions about Mathematics.  You should probably post your question as a Question (together with what you have and haven't understood about what is going on).

Comment: Thank you for your comments @EricTowers

Comment: @EricTowers I use the notation/definition: 1) limit exists (finite) when $f\to L\in \mathbb R$, 2) limit exists (infinite) when $f\to \infty$ (or $\to -\infty$) 3) limit doesn't exist otherwise.

Comment: @user : You are, of course, free to make up whatever non-standard definitions you like.  You are also, of course, going to be misunderstood by everyone using the standard definitions unless you (repeatedly) state your definitions when you use them.

Comment: @EricTowers Indeed it is solely a matter of definition. Let consider that it is a definition currently used also at university level. I adopt it for convenience in order to distinguish the cases with oscillating functions or other similar "bad" cases not convergent nor divergent at $\infty$ (or $-\infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply we have

$$\cos x \to1^- \implies 1-\cos x \to 0^+$$

therefore

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1-\cos x}=\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{y}$$

---

As an alternative

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos x}=\frac{x^2}{1-\cos^2 x}\frac{1+\cos x}{x^2} \to 2\cdot \frac 2{0^+}$$